# Passive discouragement and less supportive senior colleagues: What should I do?

Tags: early-career, health, colleagues

I am a budding scientist (27 years old, Doctoral candidate) and a lecturer at a university. In the early stage of my career, I have achieved some significant milestones in my field. However, sometimes I experience that my senior colleagues at the university where I work as a lecturer aren't supportive of my ideas: regardless how 'brilliant' they are, they tend to not listen and discredit when I share ideas. Instead, they tend to be more interested in other older colleagues that share the same ideas as mine.

There are times that when I publish my work and share it with them; instead of discussing it, they will ignore it and as if it didn't exist. It's quite difficult to deal with and sometimes I feel discouraged, even though I know I shouldn't, but there are times when it really consumes you.

Answer (score 7):

You may be reading too much into their behavior. It is normal for academics to be interested in their own stuff and whatever supports it directly and uninterested in everything else. There may also be the effect that some of them have a long history of trust with others, but not yet with you. Hopefully this will change over time, and, in any case, if you stick around long enough then they will disappear and you will be the "older colleague".

But, under the circumstances, you seem to be doing the right thing: publishing your work. You can also seek the positive feedback you'd like to have outside your own institution, by attending conferences and expanding your circle of contacts.

But maybe they are just *jerks*. Don't let them wear you down. Finish your degree and look for employment at a more collegial place.